# Guide is telling me to destroy shadow orbs, but I have the Crimson

Tags: terraria

He is stuck telling me to combine lenses in the corruption and to destroy shadow orbs. I have combined lenses, and there are NO shadow orbs. I've already defeated the wall of flesh but he is still stuck telling me to do impossible things.

Any fixes?

Answer (score 2):

This is probably just a bug. If you have Crimson just replace 'Shadow Orbs' in your head with the Hearts (I forget their name) you see in the 'fingers' of the Crimson. I don't know what the purpose is for what he is telling you to do but for all intents and purposes Crimson and Corruption are the same thing pre-hard-mode and only slightly different in hard-mode.

Comment: I assumed this, and I have destroyed ALL of the crimson hearts in my world. He is still telling me to destroy shadow orbs.

Comment: I'd suggest killing him again. He deserves it anyway. But otherwise I don't know. I still suggest that it is just a bug. I think I have heard rumors that in hard mode Corruption shows up in Crimson worlds so maybe Shadown Orbs showed up. But as far as I know it's just a bug.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I guess it's not really a big problem, seeing as I can progress in hard mode unlocking new ores with no problem, but it's frustrating

Answer (score 0):

This is obviously a bug... BUT if you or someone else has spread the corruption into your world from a different world then maybe you have some part of the world that is corruption. You can test this by asking the dryad if she says otherwise then it is a bug